# AES Encyrption In MySQL odd table display

Tags: mysql, aes

hi I have some AES encrypted fields in my database encrypted like

AES_ENCRYPT(data, 'key')

but in the database they now look like they have lots of quesitons marks and such like in them

any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: What's the data type for the column?

Comment: varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the data in a `VARBINARY` or `BLOB` column.  By using a text column, the client, and possibly the database at some times, is trying to convert the binary, non-text data to text.  The question marks are a result of that when the binary data doesn't match to a text character.

Comment: can I change it afterwards?

Comment: @KurtisBro what do you mean?

Comment: so say I have stored data as varchar, can I then change it to varbinay, as if I try to decrypt it i just get null

Comment: @KurtisBro That might work if the data didn't get converted.  You can try it, but I don't expect it to work.  To be sure it will be decryptable later, it should be stored as binary the whole time.